# Merge csv's with some common columns and fill in Nans

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I have several csv files (all in one folder) which have columns in common but also have distinct columns. They all contain the IP column. The data looks like

File_1.csv

```
a,IP,b,c,d,e
info,192.168.0.1,info1,info2,info3,info4
```

File_2.csv

```
a,b,IP,d,f,g
info,,192.168.0.1,info2,info5,info6
```

As you can see File 1 and File 2 disagree on what belongs in column d but I do not mind which file it keeps the information from. I have tried pandas.merge but this however returns two separate entries for 192.168.0.1 with NaN in the columns present in File 1 not in File 2 and vice versa. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Edit 1:

The desired output should look like:

output

```
a,IP,b,c,d,e,f,g   
info,192.168.0.1,info1,info2,info3,info4,info5,info6
```

and I would like the output to be like this for all rows, not every item in file 1 is in file2 and vice versa.

Edit 2:

Any IP address present in file 1 but not present in file 2 should have a blank or Not Available Value in any unique columns in the output file. For example in the output file, columns f and g would be blank for IP addresses that were present in file 1 but not in file 2. Similarly, for an IP in file 2 and not in file 1, columns c and e would be blank in the output file.

Comment: Could you include what you want the output to look like after you merged it?

Comment: edited to include desired output

Comment: Ive fixed the 6 columns and 5 values, and I would like to keep all the information so a and b must be kept

Comment: the IP addresses in both files are the same?

Comment: not for every entry but some are

Comment: If an IP address is in file1 and not in file2, what will column g be in the new data file?

Comment: Blank would be preferable but it could be anything like Not available etc etc

Comment: Could you update your question to reflect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This case:**

Set `IP_address` as index column and then use `combine_first()` to fill in a holes in a data_frame which is the union of all `IP_address` and columns.

```
import pandas as pd
#read in the files using the IP address as the index column
df_1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', header= 0, index_col = 'IP')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', header= 0, index_col = 'IP')
#fill in the Nan
combined_df = df_1.combine_first(df_2)
combined_df.write_csv(path = '', sep = ',')
```

EDIT: The union of the indices will be taken, so we should put the IP address in the index column to ensure IP addresses in both files are read in.

**`combine_first()` for other cases:**

As the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) states, you'll only have to be careful if the same IP address in both files has conflicting nonempty information for a column (such as `column d` in your above example). In `df_1.combine_first(df_2)`, `df_1` is prioritized and `column d` will be set to the value from `df_1`. Since you said, it doesn't matter which file you will draw information from in this case, this isn't a concern for this problem.

Comment: will this then also allow for b to contain columns not in a to still be included in the output?

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo I've editted my answer so columns not in b will be included in the output, and the union of the IP addresses from both files will be read in.

Comment: Thank you ill give this a pass at the full files and let you know how it goes

Comment: Im trying to write the end dataframe to a csv for reading however it is only containing information from df_1 if i use df_1.to_csv('output.csv',sep=',') after combining df_2 to df_1

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo Sorry, I should have mentioned this is not an inplace operation. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I am trying this on 6 files however this is proving to no avail as any information in any of the other files is not appearing in the final output file including the column names but the output file's column names are now in alphabetical order so something must be happening to them

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo Have you read in all the files setting the index_col to IP, (that's how combine_first will know how to take the union)? Then are you doing `new =a.combine_first(b)` followed by new2 = new.combine_first(c), etc. I"ll edit the post to include information for combining multiple files.

Comment: they all are opened telling them to use index_col as IP however I was not doing as new=a.combine_first(b) followed by new2=new.combine_first(c) i was continuing to use new as the variable name

Comment: You sir are amazing and have reinstalled my faith in the python community thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple dictionary should do the job.  Assume you've read the contents of each file into lists `file1` and `file2`, so that:

```
file1[0] = [a,IP,b,c,d,e]
file1[1] = [info,192.168.0.1,info1,info2,info3,info4]
file2[0] = [a,b,IP,d,f,g]
file2[1] = [info,,192.168.0.1,info2,info5,info6]
```

(with quotes around each entry).  The following should do what you want:

```
new_dict = {}

for i in range(0, len(file2[0]):
    new_dict[file2[0][i]] = file2[1][i]

for i in range(0, len(file1[0]):
    new_dict[file1[0][i]] = file1[1][i]

output = [[],[]]
output[0] = [key for key in new_dict]
output[1] = [new_dict[key] for key in output[0]]
```

Then you should get:

```
output[0] = [a,IP,b,c,d,e,f,g]
output[1] = [info,192.168.0.1,info1,info2,info3,info4,info5,info6]
```

Comment: then to write to a csv file i would just iterate over the output?